# How does Qiskit Aqua commutator work?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Commutation operation is essential in quantum mechanics, but when I was trying to use the commutator of IBM qiskit I find something confusing.

Here comes the problematic code.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
from qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy import commutator

qr0=QuantumCircuit(1)
qr1=QuantumCircuit(1)
circ0.x(0)
dm0=DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ0)
circ1.z(0)
dm1=DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ1)
```

The upper codes generates two Density Matrices, and since they are matrices, mathematically we can compute their commutator, but then after you run `commutator(dm0,dm1)` you'll find that it's not working. Even if you try some other types like input two Operators or input the detailed matrices(`dm.data`) but it is just raised an error. E.g. in the lower code when the detailed matrices case returns an error.

```
dm0=Operator(dm0)
dm1=Operator(dm1)
commutator(dm0.data,dm1.data)
```

The errors that qiskit reports are nearly identical so I just put one of them as an example.

[image]

I know numpy or scipy can help me in circumventing the trouble, but I still want to ask: have anyone meet this before? Do you know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with [the `commutator` documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy.commutator.html), it works on [`WeightedPauliOperator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy.WeightedPauliOperator.html), not on numpy arrays.

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy import commutator
from qiskit.aqua.operators import WeightedPauliOperator
from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli

pauli_a = 'X'
pauli_b = 'Z'
coeff_a = 0.5
coeff_b = 0.5
pauli_term_a = [coeff_a, Pauli.from_label(pauli_a)]
pauli_term_b = [coeff_b, Pauli.from_label(pauli_b)]
op_a = WeightedPauliOperator(paulis=[pauli_term_a])
op_b = WeightedPauliOperator(paulis=[pauli_term_b])

print(commutator(op_a, op_b))
```

```
Representation: paulis, qubits: 1, size: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this will work.